# dynamic link firebase did not open app store when app uninstalled

Tags: ios, firebase-dynamic-links

i implemented firebase method of ios dynamic link. it works fine when app installed, it open app. but when app uninstalled, dynamic link did not open app store of the app.

i read firebase and it said need to add efr=1. how to add it?
example my link: https://c4334.app.goo.gl/pHFzwRKfqzdP1LZ37

i tried to add it like this:
https://c4334.app.goo.gl/pHFzwRKfqzdP1LZ37?efr=1 
but when i click the link it said 404

how to implement dynamic link so it can open app store when app uninstalled?

how to use efr=1? is that efr=1 in example link correct? please guide me to correct redirect to app store example link

Answer (score 5):

I think you need to add the `isi` parameter to your URL with the value set to your app's App Store ID.

You can read about all the parameters [here](https://firebase.google.com/docs/dynamic-links/create-manually)

You can also use the [Firebase Console](https://console.firebase.google.com/project/_/durablelinks/links/) to create Dynamic Links which can be simpler as it puts all the information into the link for you.

[General info about all the ways you can create Dynamic Links](https://firebase.google.com/docs/dynamic-links/create-links)

Comment: I already read it before and I think it come from firebase console, because the code is inside the app, and if the app still not installed or uninstalled, it will not trigger the code that I set inside the app. I think it come from unproperly set appID and teamID inside firebase console

Comment: got the same issue :(

Comment: You also need to add the Apple Store id to your firebase project for your iOS app

Answer (score 4):

You need to add the `isi` param to your URL **AND** you have to set properly the `ID App Store` field in the settings of your IOS project in the firebase console, then the dynamic link on IOS will know where to look and redirect on the app store following your app store ID.

Your `App Store ID` is your app `Apple ID` and you can find it in the appstore connect page in your App information section.

Answer (score 1):

I was facing same issue when I was using REST Api call

```
POST https://firebasedynamiclinks.googleapis.com/v1/shortLinks?key=api_key
```

Reference : https://firebase.google.com/docs/dynamic-links/rest#create_a_short_link_from_parameters

I added `iosAppStoreId` in request payload to make it working.

Sample request payload will be now as below.

```
{
    "dynamicLinkInfo": {
        "domainUriPrefix": "https://test.page.link", // YOUR DOMAIN LINK
        "link": "https://post.test.com/12345", // YOUR DEEPLINK
        "androidInfo": {
            "androidPackageName": "com.test.app" // YOUR ANDROID PACKAGE ID
        },
        "iosInfo": {
            "iosBundleId": "com.test.app", // YOUR IOS BUNDLE ID
            "iosAppStoreId": "1906676749" // YOUR IOS APP STORE ID
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: You also need to add the Apple Store id to your firebase project for your iOS app

Comment: having same issue , already add app id and team id in firebase project too